# Cassandra DELETE query not being executed when racing UPDATE

Tags: cassandra

I'm running a DELETE query in Cassandra. This happens concurrently with several UPDATE queries which have an IF EXISTS clause. The expected behaviour is that when the DELETE arrives, it will be executed and then subsequent UPDATEs will not be executed as the IF EXISTS clause will resolve as false as the delete will have occurred.

This is not a consistency issue as the Cassandra 'cluster' is a single node running in a docker container. I have looked at the logs and have captured at trace level the cassandra log output for a successful delete compared to an unsuccessful delete. It seems in the failing case, the delete is simply not being executed.

**Successful delete:**

The delete gets processed at line 2.

The update is processed immediately after and is not applied because the deleted row no longer exists.

```
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-4] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,012 Message.java:516 - Received: QUERY DELETE FROM monitored_compliance_rules WHERE organisation_id='2' AND id=2cde2468-1c04-480c-9e24-681c04480c9e[pageSize = 5000], v=4/v4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-4] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,012 QueryProcessor.java:212 - Process org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.DeleteStatement@77bb560f @CL.LOCAL_ONE 
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,013 Message.java:516 - Received: EXECUTE 346d975e583adeeb6aadbf60e16d9d26 with 4 values at consistency LOCAL_ONE, v=4/v4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,013 QueryProcessor.java:519 - [1] 'java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4 cap=4]'
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,013 QueryProcessor.java:519 - [2] 'java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=12 cap=12]'
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,013 QueryProcessor.java:519 - [3] 'java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1 cap=1]'
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,013 QueryProcessor.java:519 - [4] 'java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]'
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,013 QueryProcessor.java:212 - Process org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.UpdateStatement@6d551622 @CL.LOCAL_ONE
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,013 MessagingService.java:945 - /172.18.0.4 sending PAXOS_PREPARE to 3255@/172.18.0.4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,013 MessagingService.java:948 - Message-to-self TYPE:MUTATION VERB:PAXOS_PREPARE going over MessagingService
TRACE [MutationStage-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,015 MessagingService.java:945 - /172.18.0.4 sending REQUEST_RESPONSE to 3255@/172.18.0.4
TRACE [MutationStage-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,015 MessagingService.java:948 - Message-to-self TYPE:REQUEST_RESPONSE VERB:REQUEST_RESPONSE going over MessagingService
TRACE [RequestResponseStage-5] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,016 PrepareCallback.java:64 - Prepare response PrepareResponse(true, Commit(bdbe3ea0-6e20-11e7-bc6a-52488cbcfc11, [analytics.monitored_compliance_rules] key=2 columns=[[] | [days_processed days_to_process state]]
    Row: id=4c6ddcbe-c3f7-4287-addc-bec3f7628718 | days_processed=0, days_to_process=180, state=initializing), Commit(13814000-1dd2-11b2-8080-808080808080, [analytics.monitored_compliance_rules] key=2 columns=[[] | []])) from /172.18.0.4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,016 ReadCallback.java:101 - Blockfor is 1; setting up requests to /172.18.0.4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,016 AbstractReadExecutor.java:116 - reading data locally
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-4] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,016 Tracing.java:188 - request complete
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-4] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,017 Message.java:535 - Responding: EMPTY RESULT, v=4/v4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,018 ReadCallback.java:147 - Read: 5 ms.
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,019 Tracing.java:188 - request complete
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,019 Message.java:535 - Responding: ROWS [[applied](analytics, monitored_compliance_rules), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType]
 | false
---, v=4/v4
```

**Unsuccessful Delete**

The delete is received on line 1 but is not processed.

The update is received on line 2 and occurs successfully as the IF EXISTS clause resolves to true as the delete never happened.

```
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,353 Message.java:516 - Received: QUERY DELETE FROM monitored_compliance_rules WHERE organisation_id='2' AND id=5c1b69cd-653d-4d6b-9b69-cd653dbd6b8c[pageSize = 5000], v=4/v4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,369 Message.java:516 - Received: EXECUTE 346d975e583adeeb6aadbf60e16d9d26 with 4 values at consistency LOCAL_ONE, v=4/v4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,369 QueryProcessor.java:519 - [1] 'java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4 cap=4]'
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,369 QueryProcessor.java:519 - [2] 'java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=12 cap=12]'
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,369 QueryProcessor.java:519 - [3] 'java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1 cap=1]'
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,369 QueryProcessor.java:519 - [4] 'java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]'
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,369 QueryProcessor.java:212 - Process org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.UpdateStatement@6d551622 @CL.LOCAL_ONE
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,369 MessagingService.java:945 - /172.18.0.4 sending PAXOS_PREPARE to 3263@/172.18.0.4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,370 MessagingService.java:948 - Message-to-self TYPE:MUTATION VERB:PAXOS_PREPARE going over MessagingService
TRACE [MutationStage-2] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,374 MessagingService.java:945 - /172.18.0.4 sending REQUEST_RESPONSE to 3263@/172.18.0.4
TRACE [MutationStage-2] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,376 MessagingService.java:948 - Message-to-self TYPE:REQUEST_RESPONSE VERB:REQUEST_RESPONSE going over MessagingService
TRACE [RequestResponseStage-4] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,377 PrepareCallback.java:64 - Prepare response PrepareResponse(true, Commit(bdbe3ea0-6e20-11e7-bc6a-52488cbcfc11, [analytics.monitored_compliance_rules] key=2 columns=[[] | [days_processed days_to_process state]]
    Row: id=4c6ddcbe-c3f7-4287-addc-bec3f7628718 | days_processed=0, days_to_process=180, state=initializing), Commit(13814000-1dd2-11b2-8080-808080808080, [analytics.monitored_compliance_rules] key=2 columns=[[] | []])) from /172.18.0.4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,378 ReadCallback.java:101 - Blockfor is 1; setting up requests to /172.18.0.4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,378 AbstractReadExecutor.java:116 - reading data locally
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,379 ReadCallback.java:147 - Read: 10 ms.
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,380 MessagingService.java:945 - /172.18.0.4 sending PAXOS_PROPOSE to 3264@/172.18.0.4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,380 MessagingService.java:948 - Message-to-self TYPE:MUTATION VERB:PAXOS_PROPOSE going over MessagingService
TRACE [MutationStage-2] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,381 MessagingService.java:945 - /172.18.0.4 sending REQUEST_RESPONSE to 3264@/172.18.0.4
TRACE [MutationStage-2] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,383 MessagingService.java:948 - Message-to-self TYPE:REQUEST_RESPONSE VERB:REQUEST_RESPONSE going over MessagingService
TRACE [RequestResponseStage-2] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,383 ProposeCallback.java:62 - Propose response true from /172.18.0.4
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,383 Tracing.java:188 - request complete
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-07-21 14:27:37,383 Message.java:535 - Responding: ROWS [[applied](analytics, monitored_compliance_rules), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType]
 | true
---, v=4/v4
```

The failing does not return an exception in the driver. It just fails completely silently.

Why is this delete sometimes not happening? Is this indicative of some kind of bug in Cassandra itself?

Comment: Which version of cassandra are you using?

Comment: Latest version: 3.11

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here.

> I'm running a DELETE query in Cassandra. This happens concurrently with several UPDATE queries which have an IF NOT EXISTS clause. The expected behaviour is that when the DELETE arrives, it will be executed and then subsequent UPDATEs will not be executed as the IF NOT EXISTS clause will resolve as true as the delete will have occurred.

0) The `DELETE` may remove the node, then `IF NOT EXISTS` will be true, so it WILL issue an `UPDATE`, which is actually an UPSERT (insert if not exists), so based on your description (if it's not typo'd), it's doing the correct thing?

> The delete is received on line 1 but is not processed.
>
> The update is received on line 2 and occurs successfully as the IF NOT EXISTS clause resolves to true as the delete never happened.

1) Your queries are using CL: `LOCAL_ONE`, which means the modifications are acked by a single node before returning to the client. You have no guarantee that any other nodes actually acknowledged the write, let alone a majority. Futher, even if you issue the queries to the same coordinator, the coordinator may send them to a different replica.

2) Log lines are not indicative of which order the writes are actually hitting the memtable (which requires a write to the commitlog, which may not be ordered in the way you expect).

Comment: 0) Sorry I just realised I made a mistake in the question, the query I am running is actually an IF EXISTS query, I just wrote the wrong command in the question, so the description of the expected behaviour is correct.

1) As mentioned, this is a single node cluster, so LOCAL_ONE is conceptually the same as ALL in terms of consistency.

2) Future updates several 100ms later still occur successfully in the failing case so unless the DELETE is taking several seconds to be executed (possible?) then it's probably not happening at all.